# There is any way to restore AccessControl?

Tags: c#, filesystems, access-control

I'm using C# and studying Security (`System.Security.*`), and I just ran this code.

```
SecurityIdentifier user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
FileSystemAccessRule r = new FileSystemAccessRule(user, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny);
DirectorySecurity ds = new DirectorySecurity();
ds.AddAccessRule(r);
Directory.SetAccessControl(@"C:\", ds);
```

This is crazy, yeah I know but I want to testing it. BTW now I want to restore `AccessControl` but it cannot be set.

Restoring `AccessControl` code like this:

```
SecurityIdentifier user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
FileSystemAccessRule r = new FileSystemAccessRule(user, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
DirectorySecurity ds = new DirectorySecurity();
ds.AddAccessRule(r);
Directory.SetAccessControl(@"C:\", ds);
```

But `Directory.SetAccessControl` throws `UnauthorizedAccessException`. 
Please let me know how to restore AccessControl back.